# Large Heroku Slug Size

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I have Rails 3.1 app that I'm currently hosting on Heroku. My problem is that my slug size is a staggering 58.9MB. How would you suggest that I go about determining why this slug is so big and which gems/files are the biggest contributor to this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The article [Slug Compilation](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/slug-compiler) contains several interesting details about debugging your slug size.

To reduce the slug size, you might want to:

- use a `.slugignore` file to ignore test data, sources or design files
- make sure you [set the `BUNDLE_WITHOUT` variable](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/bundler) to ignore all the bundle groups except the current environment. This is the default config for new apps, but if you created your app several months ago the variable doesn't exist and you are bundling all the gems for all environments on every deploy

Answer (score 0):

You may try to use released gems instead of directly linking to git repositories with :git => option.

Comment: I was previously doing this w/ one gem which bloated the slug size even more but I have since removed this and my slug is still 59+ MB

Comment: @Kyle, have you tried to remove Gemfile.lock and rebuild with bundle install command and git commit and upload it again?

Comment: there was a post somewhere about Heroku problems when it came to removing gems and it not actually reducing the slug size